# jQuery JS Error on .click()

Tags: jquery

When I click on the element I get the error `uncaught exception: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: .` which I'm not sure what to do with.... I see no errors

```
var tc = $('#tc-woot');
$('.sites .tab', tc).bind('click', function (e) {
    /*$(e.currentTarget).addClass('selected');*/
});
```

This error is also thrown when I comment out the entire contents of the click event.

Comment: In which browser is this happening? Are you sure that it happens on click and not before? Does it say on which line the error is happening? If not, try in Chrome - Chrome will tell you that.

Comment: It doesn't say which line, I'm using Firefox & Firebug

Comment: Try in Chrome - Chrome tells you the line: http://vidasp.net/media/chrome-error.png

Comment: @Sime - I'm not familiar with debugging JS in chrome.... is that an extension?

Comment: No, it's built in. Just press CTRL + SHIFT + I. Take your time to get acquainted, it's a great tool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the help, but it turns out the issue was not in the code I provided, but in another section of code that was applying a listener via .click() to this element when it shouldn't have.

Comment: Please leave this as a comment, not an answer

Comment: But this is the answer to my problem.  Some people skim for the checkmarks after they read the title and see that the problem is the same as theirs.  Posting this as the answer follows the common standard of answers on this site.

Answer (score 0):

JQuery might not be returning any elements.

Check to make sure your page contains elements that satisfy the "#tc-woot .sites .tab" selector.

Also if the file is encoded in utf-8 you might have invisible characters throwing errors.

It's hard to debug invisible characters. :)